# Plotting graphs of floating point numbers in java

Tags: java, graph, frameworks, floating-point

I am looking for a framework which will allow me to plot floating point numbers using Java.
I have looked around the usual places (Jung, charting etc.) but all will only allow for the plotting of integer values, it is imperative that the values remain floating point.

Anyway to the question, can anyone recommend any graphing frameworks which would allow me to work with floating point?

I have considered using gnu plot / grapher (I work on a mac) however I would like to avoid this if at all possible

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JFreechart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) works with floats. You can look at this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JFreeChart/article.html) from Lars Vogel. I modified the `createDataset()` method to include floats and it seems to work fine.

```
private PieDataset createDataset() {
    DefaultPieDataset result = new DefaultPieDataset();
    result.setValue("Linux", 29.65);
    result.setValue("Mac", 19.35);
    result.setValue("Windows", 51);
    return result;

}
```

also if you look at this [image](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/images/PriceVolumeDemo1.png), the values on the y axis are floats.